# C# convert string to decimal 4dp

Tags: c#

I need to take a string object and convert it to a decimal to 4 dp.

So for example:

```
string val = "145.83011";
decimal sss = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(val), 4);
```

bring back 145.8301 - good

However:

```
string val = "145.8300";
decimal sss = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(val), 4);
```

brings back 145.83
I need it to be 145.8300

I need it in a decimal format so can't use string format options.

Thanks
rob

Comment: You realize decimals are numbers, not strings, and `145.83` is the exact same decimal as `145.8300`, right?

Comment: Decimals don't have formatting information. That's only relevant when you convert it to a string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: They don't have formatting information, but they don't normalize either - so a decimal with a scale of 4 will always have 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use string manipulation three times:

- Parse the original text to a `decimal` value (this will preserve the original number of decimal places)
- Use string formatting to end up with a string with *exactly* 4 decimal places. (`Math.Round` ensures there are *at most* 4DP, but not *exactly* 4DP.)
- Parse the result of the formatting to get back to a `decimal` value with exactly 4DP.

So something like this:

```
public static decimal Force4DecimalPlaces(string input)
{
    decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
    string intermediate = parsed.ToString("0.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return decimal.Parse(intermediate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

I recoil from using string conversions like this, but the alternatives are relatively tricky. You could either get the raw bits, split out the different parts to find the mantissa and scale, then adjust appropriately... or you could potentially work out some sequence of arithmetic operations to get to the right scale. (Jeppe's approach of multiplying by 1.0000m may well be entirely correct - I just don't know whether it's *documented* to be correct. It would at least be worth adding in appropriate tests for the sorts of numbers you expect to see.)

Note that the above code will perform round up on halves, as far as I can tell, so 1.12345 will be converted to 1.1235 for example.

Sample with output in comments:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Force4DecimalPlaces("0.0000001")); // 0.0000
        Console.WriteLine(Force4DecimalPlaces("1.000000"));  // 1.0000
        Console.WriteLine(Force4DecimalPlaces("1.5"));       // 1.5000
        Console.WriteLine(Force4DecimalPlaces("1.56789"));   // 1.5679
    }

    public static decimal Force4DecimalPlaces(string input)
    {
        decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
        string intermediate = parsed.ToString("0.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return decimal.Parse(intermediate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: And how does that round to 4 digits?

Comment: You are right. Removing that comment. The first version of my answer was incorrect, since I based it on the example string from the question, which is not problematic (even if the question text claims so).

Answer (score 0):

Both `Convert.ToDecimal` and `decimal.Parse` *do* preserve trailing zeroes in the string (a `System.Decimal` can have at most 28-29 digits in total, so in most cases there's still room for all the trailing zeroes).

And `Math.Round(..., 4)` preserves trailing zeroes up to the fourth place after the decimal period.

Therefore the premise of the question is wrong. Your example does bring back what you want.

In any case, *consider* specifying the overload that takes in an `IFormatProvider` as well, and give `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as argument. Then the conversion is independent of the local culture.

If instead you want to handle strings like **`"145.83"`** and *append* trailing zeroes that were not in the string, use:

```
string val = "145.83";
decimal sss = Math.Round(
    decimal.Parse(val, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 1.0000m,
    4);
```

Epilog: If you don't like multiplying and dividing by numbers like `1.0000m`, use `decimal.GetBits` to get the internal representation. Adjust the integer "part" by multiplying or dividing by the appropriate power of ten, and adjust the scale "part" by subtracting or adding the corresponding number. The scale counts the number of places to move the decimal point to the left, starting from the 96-bit integer.

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal` preserves trailing zeroes too.

Comment: I think it would be worth getting rid of the first paragraph now. I'm not sure what's guaranteed about the `* 1.0000m` operation - I suspect it works (in which case it's cleaner than my approach) but it makes me somewhat nervous still.

Comment: Well, the `System.Decimal` type might not have a very precise specification (like IEEE for other types), but for example since ten times one hundred is one thousand, we get `1.0m * 1.00m == 1.000m`. One can always multiply by `1.0000m` to append four trailing zeroes, and divide by `1.0000m` to trim away four trailing zeroes (or all trailing zeroes if there were less than four). To remove all trailing zeroes, divide by `1.0000000000000000000000000000m` (twenty-eight zeroes). I understand why it makes you nervous, but it is much better than converting `decimal` to `string` and back to `decimal`.

Comment: I think my nervousness is due to having seen results which seemed to be pretty hard to predict. I'd be much more comfortable if the rules around the scale of the result were cleanly documented. I really do hate using string conversions unnecessarily (witness the number of questions on which I rail about that topic), but I'm still just about uncomfortable enough to not delete my answer (which I would otherwise do).

Comment: @JonSkeet Not sure what "results" you refer to. Some "tricky" examples: `800m/3m * 3m` has only 28 digits (its leading digit being `8`) and compares equal to `800m` (trailing zeroes do not matter when checking for equality), while `500m/3m * 3m` has 29 digits (starting with `5`) and does not compare equal to `500m`. For the first example, there is a bug in `GetHashCode()` that gives different hashes to these instances which are equal!! In the second example, different hashes is good, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet And a related example: `290m/3m * 3m` versus `170m/3m * 3m`. Here it is the intermediate quotient which has only 28 digits in the first example, but 29 in the second. Be sure not to start with a number evenly divisible by three, for examples like these. I think it is a little unfortunate that some `System.Decimal` have 29 digist, while others have only 28. It makes things unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I mean results I've seen when trying various different operations in the past... specifically to work out how different operations affect the number of trailing zeroes. I don't have examples to hand, unfortunately.